# Laravel echo strange characters

Tags: php, laravel, echo

Hey i wan't to echo something with belongsTo but the output gives me some strange characters back.

```
class Leviews extends Entity
{
public $table = 'reviews';


public function ravatar()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('User', 'author', 'username')->select('avatar');

}
```

now when i echo the data with {{ $item->ravatar }} im getting this

```
{"avatar":"avatars\/1.jpg"}
```

and it should be

```
avatars/1.jpg
```

what im doing wrong?

*edit*
here is the Controller

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Lib\Reviews\LeviewsRepository;
use Lib\Services\Scraping\Scraper;
use Lib\Services\Validation\LeviewsValidator;

class LeviewsController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Leviews repository instance.
 * 
 * @var Lib\Leviews\LeviewsRepository
 */
protected $repo;

/**
 * validator instance.
 * 
 * @var Lib\Services\Validation\LeviewsCreateValidator
 */
private $validator;

/**
 * Leviews scraper isntance.
 * 
 * @var Lib\Services\Scraping\NewScraper;
 */
private $scraper;

public function __construct(LeviewsRepository $lreviews, LeviewsValidator $validator, Scraper $scraper)
{
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('logged', array('except' => array('index', 'show', 'paginate')));
    $this->beforeFilter('news:create', array('only' => array('create', 'store')));
    $this->beforeFilter('news:edit', array('only' => array('edit', 'update')));
    $this->beforeFilter('news:delete', array('only' => 'destroy'));
    $this->beforeFilter('news:update', array('only' => 'updateFromExternal'));

    $this->repo = $lreviews;
    $this->scraper = $scraper;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}

/**
 * Display list of paginated news.
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function index()
{
    return View::make('Leviews.Index');
}

/**
 * Display form for creating new news items.
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('Leviews.Create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created news item.
 *
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::except('_token');

    if ( ! $this->validator->with($input)->passes())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors())->withInput($input);
    }

    //escape double qoutes
    $input['title'] = htmlspecialchars($input['title']);

    $this->repo->store($input);

    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.news create success') );
}

/**
 * Display single news items.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return View
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $lreviews = $this->repo->byId($id);

    if ($lreviews->full_url && ! $lreviews->fully_scraped)
    {
        $lreviews = $this->repo->getFullLeviewsItem($lreviews);
    }

    return View::make('Leviews.Show')->with(compact('news'))->withRecent($this->repo->latest());
}

/**
 * Displays form for editing news item.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return View
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $lreviews = $this->repo->byId($id);

    return View::make('Leviews.Edit')->withLeviews($lreviews);
}

/**
 * Updates the news item.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::except('_token', '_method');

    $lreviews = $this->repo->byId($id);

    if ($lreviews->title === $input['title'])
    {
        //dont check for title uniqueness when updating if
        //title was not updated.
        $this->validator->rules['title'] = 'required|min:2|max:255';
    }

    if ( ! $this->validator->with($input)->passes())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors())->withInput($input);
    }

    //escape double qoutes
    $input['title'] = htmlspecialchars($input['title']);

    $this->repo->update($lreviews, $input); 

    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.news update success') );
}

/**
 * Delete specified news item.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->repo->delete($id);       

    return Response::json(trans('main.news delete success'), 200);
}

/**
 * Updates news from external sources.
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function updateFromExternal()
{
    $this->scraper->updateLeviews();

    Event::fire('Leviews.Updated', Carbon::now());

    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('dash.updated news successfully') );
}
```

}

and here the view

```
    @if ($options->enableNews())

                @foreach($lreviews as $k => $item)

                    {{ $item->body }}
                    {{ $item->ravatar }}

                @endforeach

    @endif
```

{{ $item->body }} is without strange characters

*edit*
here the dd output

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#634 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(6) { [0]=> object(Leviews)#606 (22) { ["table"]=> string(7) "reviews" ["defaultOrderColumn":protected]=> string(10) "created_at" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(42) ["author"]=> string(7) "Clayman" ["source"]=> string(8) "Japanime" ["body"]=> string(182) "Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review " ["score"]=> int(9) ["link"]=> NULL ["title_id"]=> int(1655) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-24 16:08:34" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> string(4) "user" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(42) ["author"]=> string(7) "Clayman" ["source"]=> string(8) "Japanime" ["body"]=> string(182) "Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review " ["score"]=> int(9) ["link"]=> NULL ["title_id"]=> int(1655) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-24 16:08:34" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> string(4) "user" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) } [1]=> object(Leviews)#635 (22) { ["table"]=> string(7) "reviews" ["defaultOrderColumn":protected]=> string(10) "created_at" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["author"]=> string(18) "James Berardinelli" ["source"]=> string(9) "ReelViews" ["body"]=> string(265) "The movie is pretty to look at in a "Transformers" sort of way and moves briskly enough that it never threatens to bore, but it's hard to feel much of anything about the characters and, when it's all over, there's a sense that everything that happens is obligatory." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(64) "http://www.reelviews.net/php_review_template.php?identifier=2687" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["author"]=> string(18) "James Berardinelli" ["source"]=> string(9) "ReelViews" ["body"]=> string(265) "The movie is pretty to look at in a "Transformers" sort of way and moves briskly enough that it never threatens to bore, but it's hard to feel much of anything about the characters and, when it's all over, there's a sense that everything that happens is obligatory." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(64) "http://www.reelviews.net/php_review_template.php?identifier=2687" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) } [2]=> object(Leviews)#629 (22) { ["table"]=> string(7) "reviews" ["defaultOrderColumn":protected]=> string(10) "created_at" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["author"]=> string(10) "Steven Rea" ["source"]=> string(21) "Philadelphia Inquirer" ["body"]=> string(345) "One of the problems with The Dark World is that its monsters and angry armies and visual effects are interchangeable with Peter Jackson's Tolkien pics, with Clash of the Titans, with The Avengers, with Man of Steel, and on and on. These superhero movies. These Middle Earth movies. These mythic god movies. It's getting hard to tell them apart." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(99) "http://www.philly.com/philly/entertainment/movies/20131108_Thor_s_back__more_generic_than_ever.html" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["author"]=> string(10) "Steven Rea" ["source"]=> string(21) "Philadelphia Inquirer" ["body"]=> string(345) "One of the problems with The Dark World is that its monsters and angry armies and visual effects are interchangeable with Peter Jackson's Tolkien pics, with Clash of the Titans, with The Avengers, with Man of Steel, and on and on. These superhero movies. These Middle Earth movies. These mythic god movies. It's getting hard to tell them apart." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(99) "http://www.philly.com/philly/entertainment/movies/20131108_Thor_s_back__more_generic_than_ever.html" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) } [3]=> object(Leviews)#630 (22) { ["table"]=> string(7) "reviews" ["defaultOrderColumn":protected]=> string(10) "created_at" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["author"]=> string(12) "Simon Abrams" ["source"]=> string(14) "RogerEbert.com" ["body"]=> string(133) "Thor: The Dark World's characters are often very charming, but they're only so much fun when they're stuck going through the motions." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(58) "http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/thor-the-dark-world-2013" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["author"]=> string(12) "Simon Abrams" ["source"]=> string(14) "RogerEbert.com" ["body"]=> string(133) "Thor: The Dark World's characters are often very charming, but they're only so much fun when they're stuck going through the motions." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(58) "http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/thor-the-dark-world-2013" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) } [4]=> object(Leviews)#641 (22) { ["table"]=> string(7) "reviews" ["defaultOrderColumn":protected]=> string(10) "created_at" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["author"]=> string(10) "Mike Scott" ["source"]=> string(26) "New Orleans Times-Picayune" ["body"]=> string(213) "None of that is to say that Thor: The Dark World is a bad movie, necessarily. I would never speak ill of a man with a giant, magical hammer. At the same time, hammer or no hammer, it doesn't quite nail it, either." ["score"]=> int(40) ["link"]=> string(95) "http://www.nola.com/movies/index.ssf/2013/11/thor_the_dark_world_movie_revi.html#incart_m-rpt-1" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["author"]=> string(10) "Mike Scott" ["source"]=> string(26) "New Orleans Times-Picayune" ["body"]=> string(213) "None of that is to say that Thor: The Dark World is a bad movie, necessarily. I would never speak ill of a man with a giant, magical hammer. At the same time, hammer or no hammer, it doesn't quite nail it, either." ["score"]=> int(40) ["link"]=> string(95) "http://www.nola.com/movies/index.ssf/2013/11/thor_the_dark_world_movie_revi.html#incart_m-rpt-1" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) } [5]=> object(Leviews)#640 (22) { ["table"]=> string(7) "reviews" ["defaultOrderColumn":protected]=> string(10) "created_at" ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["author"]=> string(12) "Peter Rainer" ["source"]=> string(25) "Christian Science Monitor" ["body"]=> string(183) "My favorite moment in the movie: Astrophysicist Erik Selvig (Stellan Skarsgard) insisting on wearing only his underwear because he says he thinks better that way. Hey, whatever works." ["score"]=> int(58) ["link"]=> string(108) "http://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Movies/2013/1108/Thor-The-Dark-World-has-lost-the-spark-of-the-original" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["original":protected]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["author"]=> string(12) "Peter Rainer" ["source"]=> string(25) "Christian Science Monitor" ["body"]=> string(183) "My favorite moment in the movie: Astrophysicist Erik Selvig (Stellan Skarsgard) insisting on wearing only his underwear because he says he thinks better that way. Hey, whatever works." ["score"]=> int(58) ["link"]=> string(108) "http://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Movies/2013/1108/Thor-The-Dark-World-has-lost-the-spark-of-the-original" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2015-04-23 18:32:05" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["morphClass":protected]=> NULL ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["softDelete":protected]=> bool(false) } } }
```

*edit*

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(42) ["author"]=> string(7) "Clayman" ["source"]=> string(8) "Japanime" ["body"]=> string(182) "Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review Review " ["score"]=> int(9) ["link"]=> NULL ["title_id"]=> int(1655) ["created_at"]=> string(12) "Apr 24, 2015" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> string(4) "user" } [1]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["author"]=> string(18) "James Berardinelli" ["source"]=> string(9) "ReelViews" ["body"]=> string(265) "The movie is pretty to look at in a "Transformers" sort of way and moves briskly enough that it never threatens to bore, but it's hard to feel much of anything about the characters and, when it's all over, there's a sense that everything that happens is obligatory." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(64) "http://www.reelviews.net/php_review_template.php?identifier=2687" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(12) "Apr 23, 2015" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } [2]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["author"]=> string(10) "Steven Rea" ["source"]=> string(21) "Philadelphia Inquirer" ["body"]=> string(345) "One of the problems with The Dark World is that its monsters and angry armies and visual effects are interchangeable with Peter Jackson's Tolkien pics, with Clash of the Titans, with The Avengers, with Man of Steel, and on and on. These superhero movies. These Middle Earth movies. These mythic god movies. It's getting hard to tell them apart." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(99) "http://www.philly.com/philly/entertainment/movies/20131108_Thor_s_back__more_generic_than_ever.html" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(12) "Apr 23, 2015" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } [3]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["author"]=> string(12) "Simon Abrams" ["source"]=> string(14) "RogerEbert.com" ["body"]=> string(133) "Thor: The Dark World's characters are often very charming, but they're only so much fun when they're stuck going through the motions." ["score"]=> int(63) ["link"]=> string(58) "http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/thor-the-dark-world-2013" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(12) "Apr 23, 2015" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } [4]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["author"]=> string(10) "Mike Scott" ["source"]=> string(26) "New Orleans Times-Picayune" ["body"]=> string(213) "None of that is to say that Thor: The Dark World is a bad movie, necessarily. I would never speak ill of a man with a giant, magical hammer. At the same time, hammer or no hammer, it doesn't quite nail it, either." ["score"]=> int(40) ["link"]=> string(95) "http://www.nola.com/movies/index.ssf/2013/11/thor_the_dark_world_movie_revi.html#incart_m-rpt-1" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(12) "Apr 23, 2015" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } [5]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["author"]=> string(12) "Peter Rainer" ["source"]=> string(25) "Christian Science Monitor" ["body"]=> string(183) "My favorite moment in the movie: Astrophysicist Erik Selvig (Stellan Skarsgard) insisting on wearing only his underwear because he says he thinks better that way. Hey, whatever works." ["score"]=> int(58) ["link"]=> string(108) "http://www.csmonitor.com/The-Culture/Movies/2013/1108/Thor-The-Dark-World-has-lost-the-spark-of-the-original" ["title_id"]=> int(87) ["created_at"]=> string(12) "Apr 23, 2015" ["updated_at"]=> NULL ["temp_id"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> string(6) "critic" } }
```

Comment: Can you show your controller and view code?

Comment: Can u `{{dd($lreviews)}}` before the foreach in the view and paste the output as well?

Comment: Can you move the dd to after the the foreach and do a `{{dd($lreviews->toArray())}}` instead and paste the output again. Sorry for asking for so many things, but i cannot see that property being set on the models.

Comment: Looks like none of the items have ravatar, I have no idea how are you getting the `{"avatar":"avatars\/1.jpg"} ` output, sorry

Comment: i already have the answer thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$item->ravatar` is model and not just a string. What you see is the JSON representation of that model. To get the actual path use:

```
{{ $item->ravatar->avatar }}
```

If it's possible that not every review has has an avatar, check that with an if statement or use this:

```
{{ $item->ravatar->avatar or 'avatar/default.jpg' }}
```

Comment: ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object if im using this

Comment: No i didnt but now, and it works thanks for helping me